# Refresh timer and warning boxes in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, timer

Basically, I have a frequency that refreshes data on screen. When one of these data points goes over a set value, it sets off an error. Upon this error setting off, I want the background colour to change (like a flashing warning).

The problem I have is that I am already using a timer, and when I call a new timer (for the flash) it stops the other timer working, and I'm unaware of how to call in the previous method (being as it uses `object sender`)

Here is my code:

```
public void Freq_Change(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Freq.SelectedIndex + 1);
        _timer.Start();
        _timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }
```

and `timer_Tick`

```
   void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
//Data generator
//Value pushes to text boxes

    if (value is over 100)
        {
    Warning_Blink
    "Oh no, an error"
        }
    else
        {
     "All good"
        }
```

`Warning_Blink` has the new timer in, which then calls `warning_Tick`

In `warning_Tick`

private bool _warning = false;

```
    private void warning_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_warning)
        {
            ErrorBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
        _warning = !_warning;
        Freq_Change();
    }
```

Here where I call `Freq_Change` (which doesn't work) I want to be able to go back to the old timer (or better yet never switch between the two) so the data generation can continue.

Can anyone help me with this? I've been scratching my head for hours

Comment: Why not use a property binding and an animation to change the color instead of doing it in code?

Comment: Could you give me an example as an answer below? I'm not very good with data bindings

Comment: I agree that it may be better to use data binding than explicitly setting formatting in code-behind. But that won't address your actual question. On the other hand, without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem, it won't be possible to say what _would_ address your actual question.